# Nomencl package - combining option nomentbl with custom subgroups fails

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am trying to use the `nomencl` package ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl)) in my document and would like to format the nomenclature entries in a table, as described in the documentation (option `nomentbl`).

This works fine, unless I also try to customise the subgroups as described in the documentation (via `\renewcommand{\nomgroup}...`). The attached MWE returns the following error in the output

> `./mwe.nls:7: Missing number, treated as zero.`

and the headers in the PDF are all messed up (see below).

Can someone please shed light on this? Did I miss anything obvious? Any advice would be highly appreciated!

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Sets}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\item[\textbf{Constants}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{V}}{\item[\textbf{Variables}]}{}}}}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
The objective function minimizes total energy cost in the period under consideration.
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:obj}
  \min_x \sum_m\sum_t C_t \cdot q_m^{p,s} \cdot r_m^{p,s} \cdot x_{m,t}^{p,s}
\end{equation}
\nomenclature[c C]{$C_t$}{Electricity price in period $t$}{}{}
\nomenclature[c q]{$q_m^{p,s}$}{Output-specific power uptake of machine $m$ when producing paper $p$ in production mode $s$}{}{}
\nomenclature[c r]{$r_m^{p,s}$}{Production rate of machine $m$ for paper $p$ when run in mode $s$}{}{}
\nomenclature[s t]{$\mathcal{T}$}{Set of points in time}{}{}
\nomenclature[s p]{$\mathcal{P}$}{Set of paper types}{}{}
\nomenclature[s m]{$\mathcal{M}$}{Set of machines}{}{}
\nomenclature[v x]{$x_{m,t}^{p,s}$}{Binary variable that equals 1 if machine $m$ produces paper $p$ in production mode $s$ in period $t$, otherwise 0}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image: Messed up nomenclature in pdf document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\nomgroup` is not really well supported with the `nomentbl` option. Surely one cannot use `\ifthenelse` for supporting it, because we need to issue a `\multicolumn` command.

A workaround is to use `\pdf@strcmp` that does string comparison expandably.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{C}=\z@
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Constants}}\\%
  \else
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{S}=\z@
      \\\\\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Sets}}%
    \else
      \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{V}=\z@
        \\\\\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Variables}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature
\clearpage

The objective function minimizes total energy cost in the period under consideration.
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:obj}
  \min_x \sum_m\sum_t C_t \cdot q_m^{p,s} \cdot r_m^{p,s} \cdot x_{m,t}^{p,s}
\end{equation}
\nomenclature[c C]{$C_t$}{Electricity price in period $t$}{}{}
\nomenclature[c q]{$q_m^{p,s}$}{Output-specific power uptake of machine $m$ when producing paper $p$ in production mode $s$}{}{}
\nomenclature[c r]{$r_m^{p,s}$}{Production rate of machine $m$ for paper $p$ when run in mode $s$}{}{}
\nomenclature[s t]{$\mathcal{T}$}{Set of points in time}{}{}
\nomenclature[s p]{$\mathcal{P}$}{Set of paper types}{}{}
\nomenclature[s m]{$\mathcal{M}$}{Set of machines}{}{}
\nomenclature[v x]{$x_{m,t}^{p,s}$}{Binary variable that equals 1 if machine $m$ produces paper $p$ in production mode $s$ in period $t$, otherwise 0}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The top group has to be treated differently.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!
I do have one question though: When I copied your solution, I forgot to include `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` in my preamble and the document still compiles fine. Is it possible that string comparison is already part of the `nomencl` package?

Comment: @Hermann One of the packages you have loads `pdftexcmds` itself. None of the packages in the example code does; I'd leave the dependency nonetheless.